# jQuery cannot get the right div with parent function

Tags: jquery

Project Language: Laravel

In short I have multiple divs with the same classes containing news and every div have its own attribute "news-id" which is equal to the DB news ID. I have an AJAX request that is triggered on button click (Delete) and everything works fine expect for the response success condition where I've typed a script that fades out the div and then removes it but it looks like the script can't focus the right div to execute the fade out script. Here's what I've got:

```
        <div class="news_card" news-id="{ID}">
            **(SOME CONTENT....)**
            <a href="javascript:" class="btn_delete del_news"><i class="icon-trash"></i><span>Delete</span></a>
        </div>
        $(".del_news").on('click', function(event) {
            $(this).css("pointer-events","none");
            var ld = $(this).closest(".news_card").attr("news-id");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '{{ url("/news/delete") }}',
                data: {id: ld},
                success: function(response) {
                    if(response.status == 1) {
                        $(this).closest(".news_card").fadeOut(1200, function() { $(this).closest(".news_card").remove(); });
                        alert($(this).closest('.news_card').attr("news-id"));
                        $(this).css("pointer-events","auto");
                    } else {
                        $(this).css("pointer-events","auto");
                    }
                }, error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log(xhr.status);
                    console.log(thrownError);
                    $(this).css("pointer-events","auto");
                }
            });
        });
```

The script is successfully deleting, but the div is not disappearing. Any idea?

Comment: In your del_news click event create a variable like `$this = $(this)` and then inside your success function replace `$(this)` with `$this`

Comment: That worked! But can you explain it to me why it wasn't working with the current code?

Comment: Because `this` inside your success does not refer to your clicked element

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot.